# Win32 Common Controls initialization breaks custom controls?

Tags: c, windows, winapi

So I'm trying to initialize Common Controls and visual styling in Win32. I build a DLL containing some custom controls I wrote, and a EXE containing the GUI application.

Normally, the separation of responsibility seems to be that my DLL shouldn't worry about whether or not we're enabling window styles. It should just produce custom controls and expose them to the dependent EXE. The EXE can then decide if it wants visual styling or not, and the DLL is none the wiser.

The problem is this: I have my DLL registering its window classes in DllMain on process attach. But if I call InitCommonControlsEx in the EXE, the buttons and whatnot inside my custom controls don't show up, because the custom controls were registered before the EXE could initialize common controls.

To prove it, I forced unregistration and re-registration of my custom controls *after* the EXE called InitCommonControlsEx, and it fixed it: buttons were showing on my custom controls, with visual styling.

In an ideal world, I'd like to be able to link to my shared library in future programs, and start using the custom controls without any worries about fixing issues with common controls and styling. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is, you're not meant to register window classes or [do much of anything](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040127-00/?p=40873) in `DllMain()`.

You should provide a separate `Init()` function exported from your DLL that the app can call to register the DLL's controls, in the same way that it calls a function (`InitCommonControls()`) to register the common controls.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no problem with using RegisterClass in DllMain

Comment: @manuell you might want to check the docs for DllMain. "Calling functions that require DLLs other than Kernel32.dll may result in problems that are difficult to diagnose. For example, calling User, Shell, and COM functions can cause access violation errors, because some functions load other system components."

Comment: Yes, I know, but note the "_some functions_". I don't think RegisterClass is among them.

Comment: @manuell It doesn't actually say "some functions", it says "functions .. other than Kernel32.dll". RegisterClass is in User32.dll

Comment: "_Unfortunately, there is not a comprehensive list of safe functions in Kernel32.dll._" Anyway, OK, I may be wrong, but I am yet to see RegisterClass causing troubles.

Comment: You definitely should not call RegisterClass from DllMain. You should not call anything that lives in User32.dll from DllMain. It might work sometimes, or even all the time in your tests, but that does not make it safe or mean it won't go wrong in some situations that you haven't tested or with future versions or Windows, or programs that load different DLLs, etc. An Init function is the proper way to do things, and that's what InitCommonControls is itself; it registers a bunch of window classes.

Comment: "Calling functions that require DLLs other than Kernel32.dll may result in problems that are difficult to diagnose. For example, calling User, Shell, and COM functions can cause access violation errors, because some functions load other system components." -- MSDN explicitly lists User32.dll there as an example of something you should't call into from DllMain. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: So, if someday in the future RegisterClass calls LoadLibray I am doomed... bad news, but can live with it.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for the input, I'll add an initialization function to the DLL.